# I want to perform realtime calculation using textwatcher but it is not calculating

Tags: java, android

```
    I'm trying to perform  a real time calculation using two edit text and get the result in third edit text it is not calculating
```

e1 textchanger

@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

```
        double e1=Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString().trim());
        double e2=Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString().trim());
        double e3=e1+e2;

        et3.setText(String.valueOf(e3));

    }
});
```

et2 textchanger

```
  @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        double e1=Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString().trim());
       double e2=Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString().trim());
        double e3=e1+e2;
        et3.setText(String.valueOf(e3));

    }
});
```

et3 textchanger
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

```
        double ans=(Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString().trim()))+(Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString().trim()));
        et3.setText(String.valueOf(ans));

    }
});
```

The values of edit text is not calculated

even tried to perform calculation using text watcher in et1 and et2 the application crashes

Comment: This doesn't make sense, in textWatcher of et3, you change et3's text? this will cause an endless call to `afterTextChaged`...

Comment: how to do the calculation

Comment: What do the edit texts represent? I suppose et1 and et2 are for numbers input, what et3 stands for?

Comment: et3 is result of calculation

Comment: the above is the newly updated code

Answer (score 0):

Add the text watcher to EditText1 and EditText2. Perform the calculation `afterTextChanged` and set the value to the third EditText. **Note: Don't the add the textWatcher to your result EditText.**

Comment: Or add a simple button that triggers the calculation...without textWatchers

Comment: i wanted to do real time bro

Comment: For real-time, you need to use textWatcher or input filter. For your case, textWatcher would be sufficient.

Comment: @SanthoshKumarSrikanthaMurali see above code for et3 and u said to perform calculation in et1 and et2 it crashes again

Comment: What's the crash message? And can you post the code? @Ragnarok

Answer (score 0):

In each textWatcher (et1 and et2) you need to check whether the other edit text's text isn't null.

Probably best to check for both in both watchers:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (et1.getText() != null && et2.getText() != null) {
        double e1=Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString().trim());
        double e2=Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString().trim());
        double e3=e1+e2;
        et3.setText(String.valueOf(e3));
    }

}
```